# convolution matrix for image scaling

Tags: image-processing, convolution

Is there any way how to compute convolution matrix for Nearest Neighbor (bicubic, bilinear) image scaling (upscale/downscale)?

Comment: Convolution cannot change image size (except adding borders).

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done as a convolution because some of the operations you mentioned are not linear. Additionally, convolution by definition (multiplication by a toplitz matrix) shouldn't ever change the input and output size.

For bicubic:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation#Bicubic_convolution_algorithm

[image]

Notice the high order terms.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, convolution operation cannot change the size of the image. *However*, interpolation is a convolution operation. You just need to upsample by zero padding the image before performing the convolution (filtering) operation.

For example, say you want to interpolate a 1D signal times 2. The original signal is given by $a_0, a_1, .. , a_n$. You first zero pad it to get $a_0, 0, a_1, 0, ..$, then you filter the result. If the filter taps are `0.5, 1, 0.5`, you will get simple linear interpolation. Similar scheme can be used in 2D images for biliniear interpolation, spline interpolation, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure bilinear interpolation can be done in the Fourier domain. For example, there is a constant term and a production of the two directions and is hence nonlinear. Most interesting, useful, things aren't linear :-)